# How to prevent attacker from getting my directory

Tags: php, security, mysqli

I have a two pages one called "login" according to my username && password in db, if the login was successful, it will redirect me to another page called "insert-post" page and from this page i will insert the new posts which will be saved automatically in the database. The question is can the attacker get the two pages? and how i can prevent the attacker to navigate from the two pages or making the directory invisible to everyone except me. By the way, the two pages are inside one directory and this directory is stored in my root directory called "????".

Comment: It's pretty unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Can i make a specific directory invisible to everyone because this directory contains an important two files: Login.php and Insert-Post.php?

Comment: No you cannot. If you made them invisible, no one could use them to `login` or `insert_post`, because they would be hidden. You don't need to worry though, because you generally can't see PHP code from the browser itself.

Comment: No dear you misunderstood me. This directory is critical contain the two files which i use them to insert a post, so if anyone knows the directory he can use this against me you got it

Comment: You cannot hide the files from use, otherwise _you cannot use them either_. What you can do, is make sure the request is coming from a trusted source, such as your login form page etc.